# Trouble Installing Shapely Library on OpenWRT Linux Without Pip Support

Tags: python, linux, shapely, openwrt

I'm facing difficulties while trying to install the Shapely library on an OpenWRT Linux x86 version where I cannot use pip due to lack of support. The Python version available is 3.9.  My objective is to use Shapely, and I've attempted the following methods:

1. Downloaded the `shapely-2.0.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl` file, extracted it, and copied both the `shapely` and `shapely.libs` folders. This approach has worked for other libraries, but it results in the following error:

```py
from .lib import GEOSException  # NOQA
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shapely.lib'
```

I noticed that it's looking for the file `lib.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`, so I renamed it to `lib.so`. However, when I rerun the Python script, I encounter this error:

```py
ImportError: /rwdata/opt/gt/adv_libs/shapely/lib.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

Even though the filename suggests `x86_x64`, it seems to have an ELF class issue.

2. Tried with an older version, Shapely 1.7.1, which has a different structure and doesn't give the `shapely.lib` error. However, it raises the following error:

```py
OSError: /rwdata/opt/gt/adv_libs/Shapely.libs/libgeos_c-a68605fd.so.1.13.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

3. Attempted to install from the source using the `setup.py install` command, but it fails due to the absence of setuptools, which cannot be installed.

Am I overlooking any steps or making any mistakes in this installation process? Any guidance on how to successfully install the Shapely library in this environment would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: Linux version is x86**